# Debugging an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the created the following Async function-

```
private class CustomAsyncUtil extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private void CreateDocument(){
        try
        {
            //doing some work
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String exp = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
            android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        CustomAsyncUtil objUtil = new CustomAsyncUtil();
        objUtil.CreateDocument();
        return "some message";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message
    }
}
```

I am calling the function like this-

```
CustomAsyncUtil objUtil = new CustomAsyncUtil();
objUtil.execute();
```

To be debug I have added `if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())` inside `doInBackground()` but I don't get a break point inside `CreateDocument()`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which breakpoints can you hit?  Something sounds off to me here.

Comment: I can hit `objUtil.execute();`. Shouldn't it go inside `doInBackground` or `CreateDocument`?\

Comment: Yes, it isn't being called properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
CustomAsyncUtil objUtil = new CustomAsyncUtil();
objUtil.CreateDocument();
```

you are calling `CreateDocument()` on a *different* async task object.  If you want to call this helper method inside the same async task, then just call it directly:

```
CreateDocument();
```

An AsyncTask has a number of lifecycle methods, the most basic of which include:

```
onPreExecute()
doInBackground()
onProgressUpdate()
onPostExecute()
```

In general, all the work you do in an async task will originate in one of these entry points, then possibly including helper methods you call from the lifecycle methods.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I also overrode `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` but the debugger doesn't hit inside them anyway and there is no exception.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me.  Are you sure you are using your latest code?

Comment: I am calling `objUtil.execute();` inside `onCreate` in my activity class.

Comment: It is surrounded in `try-catch` block. Doesn't get any exception and `onCreate` executes successfully to completion.

Comment: So you are saying that if you add a breakpoint to `doInBackground` it does not get hit?  What about logging?

Comment: Here's the entire content of the class- https://pastebin.com/5YEwzjgB. I have reduced the irrelevant code. Would you take a look at it?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code.  If I code sit and debug with you, maybe we would get somewhere.  As part of my answer I believe to be correct, I will leave it here until you get the answer you need.